# Apache 302 Redirect

Tags: apache, redirect

I read [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) and here I am trying to do a 302 redirect using apache. I'm using the default Apache shipped with OSX 10.7:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.21 (Unix)
Server built:   Nov 15 2011 15:12:57
```

I tried to:

Create an `.htaccess` file and place inside:

```
Redirect temp /old.html http://localhost/new.html
```

or

```
Redirect 302 /old.html http://localhost/new.html
```

or

```
Redirect /old.html http://localhost/new.html
```

In `httpd.conf` modify the following section (note that in the conf file I see also `LoadModule alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_alias.so`):

```
<IfModule alias_module>
  Redirect /old.html http://localhost/new.html
</IfModule>
```

I stopped/started several times Apache but with no luck. What's wrong?

Thanks!

*EDIT:* By not working I mean I get a 404!

Comment: What does your access_log show?

Comment: do you have "AllowOverride" specified somewhere in your config, probably with a 'none' value?

Comment: @hovanessyan: yes, I do have new.html.

Comment: @Thilo: ::1 - - [24/Jun/2012:10:48:04 +0200] "GET /old.html HTTP/1.1" 404 295

Comment: @hovanessyan: Yes, I do have AllowOverride None in httpd.conf

Comment: Do you have more than one Apache installed? If so, are you restarting the correct one? What does `which apachectl` give you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Using [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) directive requires that [`mod_alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) is loaded.
2. Using `Redirect` directive inside `.htaccess` requires that at least `FileInfo` can be [overridden](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Override). You need to add `AllowOverride FileInfo` in the appropriate section in `httpd.conf` (there could be more than one).
3. When you make changes to `httpd.conf` you need to restart Apache. This is probably the main issue.

Comment: Did not solve the issue which was actually due a wrong path, but this is the most comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Find the following line in your httpd.conf and change it, from

```
AllowOverride None
```

To

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: Makes no difference, unfortunately.