# Enabling .htaccess for 302 redirects

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-302, bluehost

I am attempting to create an .htaccess file on an Apache server to implement 302 redirects. Hosting is provided by BlueHost.

Right now I am testing an .htaccess file which consists of just a single line:

```
Redirect http://mydomain.com/?_escaped_fragment_=about http://mydomain.com/about.html
```

The file doesn't work. After learning more, I created an httpd.conf file, which looks like this:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

One of the answers to this question ([Apache 302 Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168038/apache-302-redirect)) suggests the following may be at issue:

1. mod_alias is not loaded--how do I check whether it is or isn't?
2. Adding the httpd.conf file may require an Apache restart. Is this possible on a shared BlueHost server?

Any advice on getting the 302 redirects to work is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't match against the query string in a redirect, you'll need to use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=about$
RewriteRule ^$ /about.html [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Brilliant, sir! Works exactly as it should. Thanks very much.